# Return maximum value from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

If I have the following nested list in parenthesis:

```
[('Frank', '8'), ('Peter', '10'), ('Spank', '0')]
```

What can I do to return the maximum value and corresponding name from the list?

Desired output:

```
('Peter', '10')
```

I have tried `max(list, key=itemgetter(1))[0]` with no luck.

Comment: Change your '8', '10' and '0' into ints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert the key field to int

```
data = [('Frank', '8'), ('Peter', '10'), ('Spank', '0')]
mx = max(data, key=lambda e: int(e[1]))
print(mx)
```

output

```
('Peter', '10')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this function. It takes as input a list with the same format than in your example and returns the element with the greatest number.

```
def findMax (names): #names = [('Frank', '8'), ('Peter', '10'), ('Spank', '0')]
numbers = [] #list for storing the numbers
for i in names:
    numbers.append (int (i [1]))

return names [numbers.index (max (numbers))] #search the max value in numbers and print the names element with the same index
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `operator.itemgetter`, you should probably convert the second item of each tuple to `int`:

```py
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [('Frank', '8'), ('Peter', '10'), ('Spank', '0')]
>>> max(((k, int(v)) for k, v in lst), key=itemgetter(1))
('Peter', 10)
```

Strings do *lexographical* ordering for comparisons by default, so doing the `int` conversion is necessary in this case. You can test this out by doing `'8' > '10'` and seeing that it gives back `True`. You can read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) for more information.